# Iconics Simulator OPC Serve and C#

Tags: c#, simulator, opc

I'm developing a C# Application for OPC Access via "OPC DA Automation Wrapper 2.02"

For testing on my WIN8 machine I'm using "Iconics Simulator OPC Server 3.12"

I have 4 boolean OPCItems with different names configured on the server.

Connecting, reading the OPCItems works fine.

But:
If I write to ONE of them, the monitor (OPC DataSpy 9.01) and other tools are showing that ALL OPCItems have changed. The Change Event appears for all OPCItems

To check this behaviour, I've written the same application with VisualBasic 6 - same result!

What is wrong, my code or the Simulator Server?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OPCAutomation;

namespace opc {
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    OPCGroups opcGroups;
    OPCGroup opcGroup;

    bool aliveToggle;
    Timer aliveTimer;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        OPCServer opcServer = new OPCServer();
        opcServer.Connect("Iconics.SimulatorOPCDA.2");
        opcGroup = opcServer.OPCGroups.Add("Gruppe1");

        opcGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("BOOL_1", 1);
        opcGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("BOOL_2", 2);
        opcGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("BOOL_3", 3);
        opcGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("BOOL_4", 4);

        opcGroup.UpdateRate     = 10;
        opcGroup.IsActive       = true;
        opcGroup.IsSubscribed   = true;

        aliveTimer = new Timer();
        aliveTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(sendAlive);
        aliveTimer.Interval=1000;
        aliveTimer.Start();

        }

    private void sendAlive(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        aliveToggle=!aliveToggle;
        opcGroup.OPCItems.Item(2).Write(aliveToggle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try that against some other server, for example [Prosys OPC Simulation Server](http://www.prosysopc.com/products/opc-ua-simulation-server/). I they both fail, the problem is in your code. I cannot spot any problems from your code.

Comment: Thanks for participation. I've tried working with WTOPCSvr from WinTech - no Prob. So I think there must be something wrong configured with "Iconics Simulator"...

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix is whenever adding a tag that needs to be event notified independently it should have it's own group, because unfortunately change events are fired on a group basis instead of a tag basis.